# How to add random-length padding in spring rest application to prevent breach attack?

Tags: spring, tomcat, compression, gzip, breach-attack

Our application was deployed in tomcat. We have gzip compression enabled in server.

How to add random-length padding in spring rest application  to prevent breach attack?